# Xcode - Importing different header file with same name based on Target

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, ios, header-files

I have a project with multiple targets each of which builds a pretty similar versions of the app but with different images assets and plists. For plists/images that's fine but I use the ShareKit and Appirater frameworks which have header files with #defines for their config. For each version I believe need to import a different version of this header file, as the config is different for each app built by each target.

So target A has SHConfig.h
and target B has a DIFFERENT SHConfig.h

I could edit the source for these frameworks to import different headers based on the target but that'd be messy when I come to upgrade the frameworks.

Is there a better way to import different header files (with the same name) based on the target?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming they're in different directories, set the Header Search Paths in each target to put the correct directory first.

You may want to set it to something like `$(SRCROOT)/foo:$(HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS)`, though I'm not sure whether that's necessary.

Comment: For two files to have the same name, they HAVE to be in different directories.

Comment: Thanks Peter, works well. An alternative that was suggested was to create my own "master" SHKConfig.h and define #ifdefs in that to pass off to other files. This has minimal overhead and less reliance on the build tools. Both solutions seem to work.

Comment: I did exactly that and it doesn't work. I have one target that looks for the header in the other target's folder. Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Rafa: Make sure you're using the correct build setting (there are several related to search paths), and that you're specifying the needed directory's path correctly (particularly tricky if it's in a build product; e.g., if the other target builds a framework). Note that naming a specific file within the search path *does not* work: All of the paths must refer to directories.

Answer (score 1):

What I found useful was to put the Common directory name in the header search path, and then to use a different #import. My directory structure was Common/Views/v1 and Common/Views/v2. I wanted the v1 for one target and the v2 for another.

In my case, the search path I used in Header Search Paths was:

```
$(SRCROOT)/../Common/
```

Then, I used:

```
#import <Views/v2/ActivityIndicator.h>
```

In the target that needed the second version (this finds $(SRCROOT)/../Common/Views/v2/ActivityIndicator.h).

Oddly, the other target (the first one I created) is fine without specifying the full path. I.e.,

```
#import "ActivityIndicator.h"
```

works to find $(SRCROOT)/../Common/Views/v1/ActivityIndicator.h

Answer (score 0):

Following process solved the issue for me

Select specific target
Under "Build Phases" --> add "New Headers Phase" --> Expand "Headers" --> click on add(plus symbol) and --> browse to the file to be added specific for the target. (It will add file under 'project' section).

Repeat the process for other targets. 
Tested on Xcode 10.2