# Classes and headers for multiple targets in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, header-files

I have an `@interface` for class `Foo` defined in the header `Foo.h` and the corresponding implementation in the file `Foo.m`. If I add another implementation `Foo.m` of the class in a different directory to the Xcode project, I can specify the "Target Membership" in the "File" tab of the "Utilities" bar to assign the implementation to a specific target.

However, this does not work for header files. If I add a different header `Foo.h` for class `Foo` then I can not assign a "Membership" in the "File" tab of the "Utilities" bar. I always get an error "Duplicate interface for class '`Foo`'", and then several errors "Property has a previous declaration" for each property I declare.

How can I use a class defined in different headers with the same name for different targets using Xcode 4.5.2?

**UPDATE:** I had already tried the solution suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868716/xcode-importing-different-header-file-with-same-name-based-on-target?rq=1) and it doesn't work in Xcode 4.5.2, the error message is as posted above.

Comment: Is the class just a little different or completely different between the two targets?

Comment: It is just "a little" different, with "a little different" meaning that a few properties and methods are removed and different ones added. There are enough things that remain identical to cause several of the "Property has a previous declaration" error messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your Foo class is only partially different between the two targets then I would suggest that you have one Foo.h and one Foo.m. You then use compiler directives to deal with the differences.

Go to the build settings for each target and add a flag under "Other C Flags". For example, for target A you can add:

```
-DTARGETA
```

and for target B you can add:

```
-DTARGETB
```

Then in Foo.h you can do:

```
@interface Foo : NSObject

@property commonProperty;
#if defined(TARGETA)
@property targetAProperty;
#elif defined(TARGETB)
@property targetBProperty;
#endif

@end
```

Do something similar for Foo.m.

Comment: This is a possible solution, albeit there are a few issues: a) It is difficult to read, b) the `#ifdef` statements in Xcode may cause problems when parsing the source in the IDE (I have noticed that preprocessor macros generally cause inconveniences/problems with code completion and similar things), c) I need to keep two distinct branches of code in both the header and the source file which makes coding errors more likely if I make a mistake on the preprocessor level.

Comment: a) Yes, this is a minor issue. b) The code for the currently selected target is fine. Typing code for the other target does cause problems for code completion. When working on code for a specific target, make sure that is the currently selected target in Xcode. c) Having this in one pair of files is easier than with two pairs of files.

Comment: I guess for the time being (i.e., until the bug is fixed in Xcode) I will create a separate project, instead. Thanks for your response, though.