# Duplicate class issue while linking a framework in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to Link a framework in your project where framework containing a class whose name is exactly the same of yours.?.I know that there is solution if we need to import same header name in two different target,because targets can be configurable.My case is different . For me I have a framework which have a file named a.h and it's a.m (For clarity let "a" be AppDelegate).The project where I want to use that framework also contains both(AppDelegate).So how to configure that I can run framework inside that project

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode - Importing different header file with same name based on Target](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868716/xcode-importing-different-header-file-with-same-name-based-on-target)

Comment: you dont, frameworks should be prefixed with something to differentiate the classes from where they are used, hence why apples framework stuff has `NS` `CG` `UI` etc in front of all their framework classes/objects. if it has a prefix already that makes it the same as yours, you will have to rename yours unfortunately.

Comment: The case is that we already have a big project which we need to convert to a framework.So my intention is to get an easy solution rather than renaming the framework classes.

Comment: The refactoring tools in Xcode or AppCode make the renaming process easier, but I don't think there's any other way around this.